# How to save values to array from php form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Here i have a form with action to another page which inserts the values to database.i also have some fields in the same form which i want only those field value to be stored in `php` array

code:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="product-form" method="post" action="files/insert.php" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product_name">Product Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Iphone 5c" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product_price">Product Price</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="product_price" id="product_price" placeholder="36,000" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Description about product</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                       <textarea class="responsive-textarea" rows="2" id="textarea" name="product_description" placeholder="Enter a short synopsis"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product_life">Life of product</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_life" id="product_life" placeholder="6years, 5 years, 2 years" required>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="refurbishment_factor">Refurbishment Factor</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refurbishment_factor" id="refurbishment_factor" placeholder="1.1, 2.1, 3.1" required>
                    </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="insurance_factor">Insurance Factor</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="insurance_factor" id="insurance_factor" placeholder="1.1, 2.1, 3.1" required>
                    </div>
            </div>



                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="walden_product_price">Price on walden</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="walden_product_price" id="walden_product_price" placeholder="36000" required readonly>
                      <span style="color:red;">Walden price to be later calculated by walden as per the logistics</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pro_url">Reference URL</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="URL" class="form-control" name="pro_url" id="pro_url" placeholder="http://www.amazon.com" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="proposed_by"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <?php echo '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="proposed_by" id="proposed_by" value="'.($_SESSION['user_id']).'">'; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="proposed_by_user"></label>



                      <div class="user-box">        
                         <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="invite-1">Member 1 email</label><div class="albox col-sm-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required=""></div></div>

                         <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="invite-2">Member 2 email</label><div class="albox col-sm-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required=""></div></div> 

                      </div>              


                  <div class="form-group">        
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add product</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

in this form i have these 2 fields where i want to store these values to php array, the fields may vary like 3,5,6.

```
<div class="user-box">        
       <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="invite-1">Member 1 email</label><div class="albox col-sm-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required=""></div></div>

        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="invite-2">Member 2 email</label><div class="albox col-sm-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required=""></div></div>              
</div>
```

when i click submit button the other values should be inserted and values of these fields should be added to array.
 how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Please set the field names like this

```
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required="">

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="invite[]" placeholder="sam@unclejohn.com" required="">
```

and you can have values in PHP like this:

```
    foreach ( $_POST["invite"] as $invite ) {
        echo $invite;
    }
```

Comment: ... and then access the values via $_POST["invite"]

Comment: for ( $i = 0; $i < count($_POST["invite"]); $i++ ) {
 echo $_POST["invite"][$i];
}

Answer (score 0):

In php you can read posted array

```
$my_array=$_POST["invite"];
for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++){
echo $my_array[$i];
//.. do what you want
}
```

Comment: A "for each" loop would be a much cleaner approach